# Is it possible to place break in python one liner ternary conditional operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I want to break the loop in else part of python one liner.

```
value='4,111,010.00400'
for i in value[-1:value.rfind('.')-1:-1]:
    if i in ('0', '.'):
        value=value[:-1]
    else:
        break
```

I wrote this code and trying to convert it to python one liner. So wrote like this

```
for i in value[-1:value.rfind('.')-1:-1]:
    value=value[:-1] if i in ('0', '.') else break
```

But not able to place **break** inside that one liner. Is it any alternative way to place it or is it possible to achieve the above in python oneliner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have discovered, you can't use `break` with the ternary operator for the simple reason that `break` isn't a value. Furthermore, while `if` statements with no `else` can be put onto one line, the `else` prevents a nice 1-line solution.

Your code strips away trailing `0` and at most one period (if everything after that period is `0`). It is thus equivalent to:

```
value = value.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

Comment: Yeah but sure would be nice if i could do:
`break if x is None else pass` :(

Comment: The syntax is:

`(condition ? expr_true : expr_false);`

`expr_true` and `expr_false` must have a common type (which will be the result of the ternary operator). `break` is not an expression, it is a statement, so it won't work.